# How to assign event from one element to another?

Tags: javascript, events, attachment

without JQuery.

for example, I have a form

```
<form name="a" onsubmit="alert(this.name)">
```

and I have another form

```
<form name="b" onsubmit="">
```

And I need when form `b` is submitted, the name of the form was shown.

I tried

```
<form name="b" onsubmit="this.onsubmit=document.a.onsubmit(); this.onsubmit();">
```

but no success.

Comment: It'll work if you just get rid of the `this.onsubmit=` part. The problem is that you're overwriting the `onsubmit` handler of `b`, but the trying to invoke it with `this.onsubmit();`

Comment: @Crazy Train: yeah it works. is it crossbrowsered?

Comment: Yeah, this specific code should work cross browser, though I don't know how well supported it is to access an element via `document` by its `name` attribute.